# Duplicating Elements of 1D Array into 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm working a memory match game for my class (first project). I'm trying to create a method that takes a predefined number of elements from my 1D array and moves a pair of the same elements into a 2D array. These will be the two cards the user would need to pair in the game.

```java
// Method takes generated 1d array and moves those 
// elements inside the 2D array as a pair. 
// 8x8 64 words, 6x6 36 words, 4x4 16 words.
static void shuffleWords() {
    String[] WordArray1D = listTo1DArray(fileName);
    String[][] WordArray2D = new String[8][8];
    int count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row <= 8; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            if (count == WordArray1D.length) break;
            WordArray2D[row][col] = WordArray1D[count];

            System.out.printf("WordCheck[%s][%s]= %s\n", row, col, WordArray2D[row][col]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The code that I have now successfully moves 32 elements into the 2D Array, but I want to move these 32 elements twice (as in pairs) to have 64 elements inside of the 2D array (32 pairs total). Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use arrays rather than lists?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Melo! Honest to mention your first class-project (kind of homework/assignment). Can you give an example of `pair of the same elements`, please. Given two words: `"hello"` and `"world"`, __what would the pair(s)__ for these look like?

Comment: Why `WordArray2D` is supposed to have dimension `n * n` (8 * 8)?  If a _pair_ of input words needs to be creayed, the dimensions should be `n * 2`?

Comment: @daniu it's a requirement from the professor.

Comment: @hc_dev. Sorry If the phrasing came out wrong. The pairs are just duplicates of each other. I want to have 32 original elements such as "Lakers" or "Celtics" and just duplicate them. The exact instructions from the professor are "Write them twice into 2D array."

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments it's still unclear, how to form a "pair" or duplicate = "write twice into 2D array" ...

#### Assumption & Example

Assuming following `n = 4` example words as input (1D-array with each element as separat row), like:

```
https
ideone
com
TkblVW
```

Then the task expects a 2D array (with 4 rows, and 4 columns):

```
https      |https      |?     |?     
ideone     |ideone     |?     |?     
com        |com        |?     |?     
TkblVW     |TkblVW     |?     |?
```

Now they are "twice" inside the 2D array... like "pairs". But what about the remaining half? There are still 2 columns (8 cells of all 16) left `null`, illustrated by a question-mark above.

#### Issue with your code

It only copies the elements from 1D-array to the first column of the 2D-array.

I [reproduced at IDEone](https://ideone.com/eMTExZ), you can try there online. Sample input 1D-array using numbers:
`String[] words = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};`
resulted in following print-output from "shuffledWords":

```
WordCheck[0][0]= 1
WordCheck[0][1]= 2
WordCheck[0][2]= 3
WordCheck[0][3]= 4
```

Read from code and observed from test, this is copying input rows into the first column (of 4), isn't it?

Seems far away from "pairs" or "twice".

#### Need to clarify on the task first

Did the Prof. give you an example, what is expected as output.
Can you draw it or post a photograph of your sheet?

Might be, the "pairs" and "twice" is actually meant as "combinations".

Answer (score 0):

The following method creates a 2D array from the input 1D array with 2 rows, and shuffles each row separately, using various utility methods from `Arrays` and `Collections`:

```java
public static String[][] shuffleWordPairs(String ... words) {
    String[][] pairs = new String[2][words.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        pairs[i] = Arrays.copyOf(words, words.length);
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(pairs[i]));
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Test:

```java
String[][] pairs = shuffleWordPairs("good", "morning", "wonderful", "beautiful", "world");

for (String[] row : pairs) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Output:

```
[wonderful, world, good, morning, beautiful]
[world, beautiful, good, morning, wonderful]
```

---

It is also possible to create a copy array to contain 2 * N words, shuffle it, and split into 2D array, thus each row may contain duplicate values:

```java
public static String[][] shuffleWordPairs2(String ... words) {
    final int n = words.length;
    String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(words, 2 * n);
    System.arraycopy(words, 0, copy, n, n);
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(copy));
    
    String[][] pairs = new String[2][n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        pairs[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(copy, i * n, (i + 1) * n);
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Output if this method is invoked for the same input:

`String[][] pairs = shuffleWordPairs2("good", "morning", "wonderful", "beautiful", "world");`

```
[good, beautiful, world, morning, world]
[morning, good, wonderful, wonderful, beautiful]
```